# catkin_create_rosjava_xx scripts/commands not found

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ROS kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04. Have followed the instructions to setup rosjava from source mentioned in this link [catking-rosjava-workspace](http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava/Tutorials/kinetic/Installation)

Now when I try to create an empty workspace catkin_create_rosjava_pkg, it returns command not found.

Here is my ROS environment variables.,

```
 env | grep ROS
 ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
 ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/share
 ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
 ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=
 ROS_DISTRO=kinetic
 ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros
```

Is catkin_create_rosjava_xx commands not supported anymore?

Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280036/catkin_create_rosjava_xx-scripts/commands-not-found/) by [shreyasathreya](https://answers.ros.org/users/33319/shreyasathreya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check the answer here - https://answers.ros.org/question/277437/solvedrosjavacatkin_create_rosjava_pkg-command-not-found/

---

Originally posted by [shreyasathreya](https://answers.ros.org/users/33319/shreyasathreya/) with karma: 16 on 2018-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0